# How to pass the content of <option> tag in a Drop Down to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 Drop Downs in my form. The first drop down consists of 2 options, MBA and B.Tech. The second drop down will consist of subjects relating to the option selected in the first drop down. This is working fine in the display. But when I send data on to the server it sends the value of the `value` attribute. I want it to work as before i.e giving options relating to the first choice and send the content of both the drop downs to the server.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Course</label>
    <select name="course" class="form-control course" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option value="1">B.Tech</option>
      <option value="2">MBA</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Stream</label>
    <select name="stream" class="form-control stream" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option value="1">Electronics and Computer Engineering </option>
        <option value="1">Mechatronics Engineering </option>
        <option value="1">Civil Engineering </option>
        <option value="1">Electronics and Communication Engineering </option>
        <option value="1">Mechanical Engineering  </option>
        <option value="1">Electrical Engineering </option>
        <option value="1">Computer Science and Engineering  </option>
        <option value="2">Marketing </option>
        <option value="2">Banking and Finance</option>
        <option value="2">Pharmaceutical Management </option>
        <option value="2">Sales and Retail Marketing </option>
        <option value="2">Healthcare Management in collaboration with Fortis Healthcare </option>
        <option value="2">Human Resource Management in collaboration with ManpowerGroup </option>
        <option value="2">Pharmaceutical Management </option>
        <option value="2">Logistics and Supply Chain Management in collaboration with Safeducate </option>
        <option value="2">Insurance and Financial Planning </option>
        <option value="2">Financial Markets Practice in collaboration with BSE Institute</option>
        <option value="2">Health Information Technology in Strategic Partnership with Frost and Sullivan </option>
        <option value="2">Sales and Retail Marketing </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

The above is my HTML. Below is the Javascript I am using to give me options relating to the first choice.

```
<script>
    $(".course").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options', $('.stream option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('.stream').html(options);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text of the option to be sent to the server, don't overwrite the `value` attribute with the grouping for the parent dropdown option. Instead you could use a `data` attribute to filter on, like this:

```js
$(".course").change(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  if (!$el.data('options')) {
    $el.data('options', $('.stream option').clone());
  }
  
  var id = $el.find('option:selected').data('value');
  var $options = $el.data('options').filter('[data-value=' + id + ']');
  $('.stream').html($options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Course</label>
  <select name="course" class="form-control course" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option data-value="1">B.Tech</option>
    <option data-value="2">MBA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Stream</label>
  <select name="stream" class="form-control stream" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option data-value="1">Electronics and Computer Engineering </option>
    <option data-value="1">Mechatronics Engineering </option>
    <option data-value="1">Civil Engineering </option>
    <option data-value="1">Electronics and Communication Engineering </option>
    <option data-value="1">Mechanical Engineering </option>
    <option data-value="1">Electrical Engineering </option>
    <option data-value="1">Computer Science and Engineering </option>
    <option data-value="2">Marketing </option>
    <option data-value="2">Banking and Finance</option>
    <option data-value="2">Pharmaceutical Management </option>
    <option data-value="2">Sales and Retail Marketing </option>
    <option data-value="2">Healthcare Management in collaboration with Fortis Healthcare </option>
    <option data-value="2">Human Resource Management in collaboration with ManpowerGroup </option>
    <option data-value="2">Pharmaceutical Management </option>
    <option data-value="2">Logistics and Supply Chain Management in collaboration with Safeducate </option>
    <option data-value="2">Insurance and Financial Planning </option>
    <option data-value="2">Financial Markets Practice in collaboration with BSE Institute</option>
    <option data-value="2">Health Information Technology in Strategic Partnership with Frost and Sullivan </option>
    <option data-value="2">Sales and Retail Marketing </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is sending the content of the second drop down but not the content of the Course dropdown. there I am still getting 1 or 2 as value

Comment: In that case you need to use the same `data` attribute there too. I've updated the answer for  you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It's a bit of a work-around, it is probably better for you to have two separate drop-downs, have them both hidden and then just show the relevant when you select an option from the first drop-down.

```
$('.course').change(function() {

    let id = $(this).val();

    $(document).find('.stream option').each(function() {

        let value = $(this).val();
        let text = $(this).text();

        if(id != value) $(this).remove();

        $(this).val(text);

    });

});
```

**What does this code do?**

Simple, when you select an option from .course we will record the value in a variable called 'id', we then loop through each of the options in the .stream select and see if its value matches the one we previously stored in 'id'.

If it does not match, we remove this option from the select.

Finally, we set the value of the remaining options to the full text within the option.

**Is there anything I should be aware of?**

If a user selects a course, and then changes their mind and selects a different course, the .stream select will be empty, you can either write some code to sort this out or I'm sure someone else will provide you with an answer that suits you better than mine - in a bit of a rush at the moment.